# in a YAML list, why does "-" before the work vs no dash

Tags: yaml, jekyll

This is purely so I can understand the logic of the situation.

when using this jekyll setup

```
{% for documents in site.data.documents %}
<h5>{{documents.family}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

why does starting the yaml code with a dash work vs without a dash?

this works

```
- family:
  - family-name: "watchdog"
    product:
    - name: "Watchdog 2 Mesh"
      doc-type: "data-sheet"
      language:
        - version: "english"
```

this does not

```
  family:
  - family-name: "watchdog"
    product:
    - name: "Watchdog 2 Mesh"
      doc-type: "data-sheet"
      language:
        - version: "english"
```

Comment: In the YAML specification the collection types are called sequence and mappings. Lists are probably what sequences are are mapped to in the programming language you are used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML has to confirm to what the application doing the parsing expects. In this case leaving out the dash makes the toplevel a mapping instead of a sequence (with one element) and jekyll expects a sequence at the top level.